# issue with changing UIButton background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I have the following code which basically just initialize a UIButton.

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    self.button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
   [self.voteSpot setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.voteSpot setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainButton-Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(button) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
        self.button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        self.button.center = center;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.button];
```

When I press on the button I want the button background to be changed, so in the target I have the following:

```
- (void) button
{

    [self setSelectedViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]];
    [self setTabBarWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Map-Profile.png"]];
}
```

The issue is that when the app first initially loads, I have to press the button twice to make the background change.. why is this? the first time I tap the button this doesn't change the button background image. Any idea?

Comment: If I'm right, the setBackgroundImage:forState: method is a configuration method, so setting it once when you initialize your UIButton should be enough for it to change the image for all the declared states. Also, never ever use the setter with alloc init, it does a double initialization which causes a leak there, or you can just set an autorelease UIButton to avoid the leak. (self.button = [[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: You appear to be setting the "Selected" image for `UIControlStateNormal` in your selector. The default UIButton doesn't really have any selected functionality.
What is it that you wish to have happen?

Comment: so the button initial background color is red when I tap I want it to be blue and be blue..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'd start by creating the button using `+buttonWithType` instead of `+alloc` and `-init`. The `buttonType` property is read only, and initializing the button with `-init` doesn't let you set the type.

Comment: I did that previously and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You should set the highlighted/selected backgrounds before the user can tap the button. In other words, move the first two lines from the action method to where you create the button.

Comment: yup.. I did that too and it is still the same thing, had to tap the button twice to get the effect